# Is there a YAML Database?

Tags: mongodb, yaml, database

I like YAML's data model a lot, preserving most of the simplicity of JSON and extending it with a few sometimes-important features like custom data types and references.

So is there any way to store a lot of data in the YAML data model (or something very similar) and query it using an index? Like a YAML database, analogous to [XML databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database) or JSON databases like Mongo DB. Or is there a mapper from YAML to something like Mongo DB that lets me transparently use it as a YAML store?

I haven't found anything so maybe there aren't any. Why would that be? Is it a stupid idea or is YAML simply too young and they will come?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for ...? There are plenty of libraries to convert from YAML to platform specific models (many listed on [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)). From those models, you could use one of the many platform drivers for MongoDB to store and query/etc.

Comment: I'm not so much interested in importing YAML files, but rather having a database with a data model similar to YAML. I updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: What's the difference between any of the many dozens of document based "NoSQL" databases and the "YAML" database you're proposing?

Comment: Basically the difference between YAML and JSON (or BSON for mongo). For me it's particularly that you can have [custom types in YAML](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2503753).

Comment: and ordered key-value pairs as well as native references.

Comment: fields in BSON documents are ordered. Strictly speaking, you could formulate a YMAL-to-BSON codec that encodes custom types as binary values in BSON, which would provide you with the effect you want.

Comment: @tychoish, are you sure BSON fields are ordered? I couldn't find anything but [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/bson/lLJviAyN_po), which suggests they are unordered.

Comment: You can write YAML in coffeescript and it will compile to JSON.

Comment: I second this need for a YAML database. Something that supports dumping tagged documents into it where the tags specify the database name, collection, and perhaps the query used to store it, validation info, etc. Every document can be stored with the query used to store it as metadata :P And you'd have one-to-many references. Problem is how would you deal with many-to-may. Well, there are a lot of problems. But yeah, this would be awesome.

Answer (score 5):

> Or is there a mapper from YAML to something like Mongo DB that lets me transparently use it as a YAML store?

Not directly as far as I know.

The main problem seems to be that Mongo DB's interface is based on a hash (i.e. key-value pairs). So in essence you are asking if there is a mapper from YAML to a hash. The answer is no simply because YAML can store arbitrary structures while hashes cannot.

But if you're willing to simplify your objects, you might be able to partially do this:

```
class SomeObject
  def initialize
    @bob = 'abc'
    @fred = 'cde'
  end

  def to_hash
    h = {}
    instance_variables.sort.each do |v|
    h[v] = instance_variable_get(v)
  end
  return h
end
```

If you look at the to_yaml code you'll see that it's very similar to the to_hash method (because that's where I got the idea).

Note you'll probably need a from_hash method as well. And you probably want to start working out a scheme for classes with instance variables that are objects (i.e. not just Strings, Symbols, etc.)

Now the mongo code to insert the item:

```
include Mongo
db = MongoClient.new.db('test')
stuff = db.collection('stuff')
item = SomeClass.new()
... other code ...
stuff.insert(item.to_hash)
```

I realize this doesn't answer your question directly, but hopefully it still helps.

John

Answer (score 3):

Updating the topic, take a look at: http://blog.varunajayasiri.com/yamldb.

"YAML database is a document database which stores documents as YAML files. The documents in the database can be maintained by simply editing the yaml files.

This database was designed to be used for systems like CMS systems, where an easy way to edit data is necessary and the number of data objects is not very high. It can be also used to store settings and configurations.

Storing the database as separate files lets you use version control systems like git on the database, which is again ideal for storing settings, configurations, blog posts and CMS content."

Answer (score 2):

`Yaml` is rather used for config purposes. It is not used for database such as MongoDB because serialization takes longer than `json`. In fact, json is not a subset of yaml (although it's close). `Json` libraries are generally faster : [stackoverflow.com/questions/2451732/](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627042/erik-aronesty)….

> If interoperability and speed are a concern, use JSON. -
>   [Erik Aronesty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627042/erik-aronesty)

Comment: Any reference about your text always are appreciate.

Comment: YAML is much faster for a human to input and read. Even if there was some slowness in how to serialize it, machine time is much cheaper than human time. Further JSON and MongoDB do not support references, a critical shortcoming. Sometimes processing speed is not the important thing you want to prioritize; sometimes development speed and client transparency are much more important.

Answer (score 1):

The http://blog.varunajayasiri.com/yamldb mention by @Marcio is abandoned, and I could not find an alternative repository for that project.

[YamlDB](https://github.com/cloudmesh/yamldb) is a Python library which manages Yaml-based textual databases.  It is very basic, supporting only write, update, delete and search.  It allows use of keys.

The [GNU recutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/) also work with textual databases. Alas, the format is easily readable and writable by hand, but it is not Yaml. It is a set of command-line tools allowing for relatively sophisticated relational database operations, including multiple tables with foreign keys and join, autoinc of counters, time-stamps, encryption, reports, consistency checking and CSV import/export.